# StratusForms DatePicker in Repeating Rows

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm using Mark Rackley's StratusForms 1.5.  In his docs and other posts, he states that datepickers work in repeating rows.

> - You can now execute code when repeating rows are added or removed, and elements on repeating rows have unique ID's so that you can use
>     things like jQueryUI DatePickers in repeating content now.

I get a datepicker on the first row, but no datepicker if the user adds a new row.

Is there a `.NewRowAdded()` event or something similar that I need to wire up in my javascript?  I can't find anything in his docs or videos that cover that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the source file stratus-forms-1.5.js, find the function definition

```
 $.fn.StratusFormsRepeatRowAdded = function (container) {}
```

change that definition to:

```
$.fn.StratusFormsRepeatRowAdded = function (container) {       
        $( "#"+container[0].cells[0].childNodes[0].id ).removeClass('hasDatepicker');
        $( "#"+container[0].cells[0].childNodes[0].id ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    }
```

In your application's javascript, do something like this in the `Init()` to set the datepicker on the initial input when the form first loads:

```
function Init()
    {

        $("#SFForm").StratusFormsInitialize({
              htmlForm: "../SiteAssets/stratus/stratus-test.html",
              queryStringVar: "formID",
              listName: "StratusTest",
              completefunc: function()
              {
                $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
                    active: 0
                 });
                 $( "#subDate" ).datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true
                });

              }
        });
    }
```